# Remove a single label from ggplot legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

Example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RcppRoll)
library(reshape2)
test_data2=data.frame(dates2015 <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by="days"), runif(365,0,1), runif(365,1,2))
colnames(test_data2)=c("Date", "var1", "var2")

var1roll=roll_mean(test_data2$var1, 21)
var2roll=roll_mean(test_data2$var2, 21)
var1roll=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,var1roll,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
var2roll=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,var2roll,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

test_data3=data.frame(test_data2, var1roll, var2roll)

test_data_long3 <- melt(test_data3, id="Date")
colnames(test_data_long3)=c("Date", "Method", "value")

group.colors <- c("#F8766D","#00BFC4","black", "black")
ggplot(data=test_data_long3,aes(x=Date, y=value, colour=Method)) + geom_line()+
  scale_colour_manual(values=group.colors)
```

In the legend that is plotted, it contains 4 variables representing the 4 lines which are drawn. I'd like to remove the final label, so that I am left with 3 items in the legend being the pink, blue and a single black line. The black line can be called 'Average' and will reference to both lines on the plot. At the moment it is distinguishing between the two average lines, when in fact, I do not want that distinction.

Thanks

Comment: Having the data + code required to make the plot is great, but it's also important to include the packages that are used to make it easy for people to help

Comment: My mistake - I completely forgot about the packages. I'll amend the code. You beat me to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd approach it - instead of having the raw and mean data in one data.frame, I'd have them separated into two.

```
test_data_long3_raw <- melt(test_data3[,1:3], id="Date")
test_data_long3_mean <- melt(test_data3[,c(1,4:5)], id="Date")
```

Then you can add a `geom_line` for each. Using `colour = "mean"` inside `aes()` gives you a legend entry, even though colour is not mapped to a variable.

```
ggplot(test_data_long3_raw, aes(Date, value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = variable)) +
  geom_line(data = test_data_long3_mean, aes(group = variable, colour = "mean")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "#F8766D","#00BFC4"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is just what I needed - Thank you!